# How do I compare xml attribute values to a list with python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to compare the value of an xml attribute to a predefined list.  I only want to retrieve the **id** and **order_num** that corresponds to an item that exists in my **products** list.

My XML:

```
<top_root>  
    <top_field name="id" cust_id="205C1534" location_id="LA15454" account_id="199911">    
        <top_group id="921">      
            <top_item id="274" order_num="1X234TTB2"></top_item>         
            <top_item id="211" order_num="1X234TTB2"></top_item>      
            <top_item id="214" order_num="1X234TTB2"></top_item>      
        </top_group>  
    </top_field>  
    <top_field name="id" cust_id="202C1214" location_id="LA12424" account_id="199911">    
        <top_group id="914">      
            <top_item id="227" order_num="1X371TTM1"></top_item>      
            <top_item id="221" order_num="1X371TTM1"></top_item>      
            <top_item id="229" order_num="1X371TTM1"></top_item>      
        </top_group>  
    </top_field>  
    <top_field name="id" cust_id="202C1214" location_id="LA12424" account_id="199911">    
        <top_group id="814">      
            <top_item id="223" order_num="1X451TTA9"></top_item>      
            <top_item id="226" order_num="1X451TTA9"></top_item>      
            <top_item id="220" order_num="1X451TTA9"></top_item>      
        </top_group>    
        <top_group id="929">      
            <top_item id="929" order_num="1X461TTA6"></top_item>
        </top_group>  
    </top_field>  
</top_root>
```

Python code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree  as ET

tree = ET.parse('xml_test_files/request.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
products = {"ITEM1": "914",
            "ITEM2": "288",
            "ITEM3": "255",
            "ITEM4": "218",
            "ITEM5": "921"
            }
for group in root.findall('./top_field/top_group'):
    order_num = []
    id = []
    if group.attrib['id'] in products.values:
        id.append(group.attrib['id'])
        for child in group:
            if child.tag == "top_item":
                order_num.append(child.attrib['order_num'])
        print(id)
        print(order_num)
```

My desired results:

```
['921']  
['1X234TTB2', '1X234TTB2', '1X234TTB2']  
['914']  
['1X371TTM1', '1X371TTM1', '1X371TTM1']
```

Try # 1:    Ran as coded above with condition `if group.attrib['id'] in products.values:`
I get this error:

```
if group.attrib['id'] in products.values:
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

Try # 2:   I have tried without the condition `if group.attrib['id'] in products.values:` and I receive this output:

```
['921']  
['1X234TTB2', '1X234TTB2', '1X234TTB2']  
['914']  
['1X371TTM1', '1X371TTM1', '1X371TTM1']  
['814']  
['1X451TTA9', '1X451TTA9', '1X451TTA9']  
['929']  
['1X461TTA6']
```

Try #3:  When I change **findall** to **iter** and leave the condition `if group.attrib['id'] in products.values:`, I no longer get an error, but my output is blank:

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Is products.values a function? Try using products.values()

Comment: products is a dictionary - keys and values listed in code

Comment: dict.values is a function. If you want its output, use dict.values(). What is the output if you use dict.values()?

Comment: Still empty - not even printing blank lists

Comment: iterfind - that works!